Cross-validated bandwidth for the derivative of the function with local quadratic estimation
I am trying to estimate non parametrically the first order derivative of a function g(x). I am estimating $g(x)$ using a local polynomial (quadratic) procedure. I know how to compute the leave-one-out cross-validated bandwidth for $g(x)$, BUT, what I would like to do is to estimate the cross-validated bandwidth for $g’(x)$ directly. My guess is that the optimal bandwidth for the derivative is not necessarily the same as the optimal bandwidth for $g(x)$, so the cross-validation on $g(x)$ is actually not what I should do. However, I have not find any source on how to do the cross-validated bandwidth for $g’(x)$, which is much harder since I do not have the equivalent of $Y_i$ for the derivative.
Any resource on how to do this? Any implementation in R, Python or Stata would also be appreciated!
So far I am implementing Fan and Gijbels (1995) RSC criterium, but it feels less adequate than a proper cross-validation (especially since the path from the original bandwidth to the derivative bandwidth is only driven by a predetermined adjusted constant). Maybe I can use the same adjusted constant in cross-validation? But this would feel « too simple ».
When I use the cross-validation, or RSC, or Rule-of-Thumb (from Fan and Gijbels, 1996) on the function (and not the derivative), the bw I get is often "too small" in the sense that the derivative is too wiggly. I tried on simulated data and the results are always MUCH better with a larger bandwidth than the one suggested. But I would like to justify my choice with a "scientific" criterium, rather than handwaving...
PS: I also tried the locfitpackage in R, by default it implement an adaptive bandwidth (using a nearest neighbor algorithm, I guess taking the 70% closest neighbors and determining an adaptive bw accordingly, but I'm not exactly sure). If I could find an "optimal" number of nearest neighbor as well, I would be fine with it.

How do you consider loocv in relation to the estimation of the the derivative? Cross validation compares estimates with known observations. Do you have a direct observation of $g'(x)$?

As I said, I estimate g'(x) using a local quadratic regression. So basically you regress Y on a constant, X and X^2 locally, weighted by a kernel with bandwidth b; and you repeat this at several values of X.
The coefficient associated to X corresponds to the local estimate of g'(x). I think it's pretty standard.
As for the optimal bandwidth, I mean "optimal" with respect to some criterium, for e.g., the leave one out cross validation to minimize the MSE.
I don't have a direct observation of g'(x), hence why I cannot do the cross validation for g'(x), I can only do it for g(x).

G.Ander, your use of the term 'bandwidth' refers to the bandwidth of the kernel or some other weights for the local fit? Before your last comment I thought that bandwidth was refering to something like a confidence interval.

Oh no I mean the bandwidth of the kernel, for example the bandwidth of the gaussian or epanechnikov kernel to weight every observations around x. Sorry if it was not clear.

Section 5.3 of Boasiako and Staudenmayer 2022 is relevant to our discussion. It confirms your assumption that "that the optimal bandwidth for the derivative is not necessarily the same as the optimal bandwidth for [the function itself]". They conclude that "the naive estimator [i.e. using CV on the function values] can only optimally estimate even-order derivatives for Local Polynomial
Regression".
In particular, a first derivative is not an even-order derivative.
I know you said that a local polynomial regression is a requirement for you, but I'm afraid what we're beginning to see in this discussion is that it is not the appropriate tool for the job.

Thanks for the resource, it's very nice. Unfortunately I really need to stick to local polynomial regression (long story short: I'm creating a new estimator that builds upon an entire literature were the main models have been estimated by local polynomial regressions for the last 20 years... So by default I need to stick to it - even though the polynomial splines may be an interesting avenue in the future!)
But I guess it may be possible to find a similar resource for local polynomial regression.

@G.Ander Gotcha. In the context of local polynomials, Ruppert et al 1995 https://sites.stat.washington.edu/courses/stat527/s14/readings/Ruppert_etal_JASA_1995.pdf propose a bandwidth estimator and though they don't discuss derivative estimation, they claim that it's a straightforward extension. If may be worth checking the citing articles for that paper.

(just in case you're not super familiar with Google Scholar, what I recommend is looking through the citing articles and searching for "derivative" https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=20000005&sciodt=0%2C21&cites=5139488785821383756&scipsc=1&q=derivative+&btnG=; I see a few things off the bat which could be of interest depending on what exactly you mean by "local polynomial", such as https://www.jstor.org/stable/24306020?casa_token=vv43dTEDTPMAAAAA%3Azu6V210jaJdpzeEPmn1lAmNU1Xjx0Xsohvs_-l82mkDlNC2J1dtIfpTQe0oppca7Re0I9-AprY34v1-OBgElXOrp4xFBXuvCTg0oW4p6dpRV_woRAUY)

@G.Ander Oh, I didn't notice that Section 5.3 of Boasiako and Staudenmayer 2022 actually considers the local polynomial case, and comes to the opposite conclusion than in the penalized spline case. I've edited my response.

Thanks that’s a very nice update! It’s fine for me if the optimal bandwidth rule for the main function does not apply to the derivative, especially if I have arguments that prove it! What surprises me is that there seems to be very little work on the optimal bandwidth rule for the derivative itself (except from Ruppert Sheather and Wand, even though they don’t do it directly either).

Example 1
You can not use a general rule of thumb that converts the bandwith for estimating $g(x)$ to a bandwidth for estimating $g'(x)$. The reason is that it depends on the situation and sometimes the bandwidth is ideally larger, other times it is ideally shorter.
The code below demonstrates this with the fit of a sine function. If this is done with quadratic polynomials then it is advantageous to have a shorter bandwidth for the $g'(x)$ estimate. On the other hand, if this is done with cubic polynomials then it is advantageous to have a longer bandwidth for the $g'(x)$ estimate.

set.seed(1)
library(signal)
k = 10

sim = function(n,p) {
    x = 0:1000
    y = sin(x/1000*k*2*pi)
    dy = cos(x/1000*k*2*pi)/1000*k*2*pi
    z = y+rnorm(length(x),0,0.4)
    yhat = sgolayfilt(z,p,n,0)
    dyhat = sgolayfilt(z,p,n,1)
    c(mean((yhat-y)^2),mean((dyhat-dy)^2))
}
sim = Vectorize(sim)

for (p in c(2,3)){

  type = c("","quadratic polynomial fits", "cubic polynomial fits")[p]

  w = seq(5,201,2)
  x = sim(w,p)

  plot(w,x[1,], log = "y", 
     xlab = "filter length", ylab = "mean squared error", main = paste0(type, "\n function value estimate"))
  plot(w,x[2,], log = "y",
     xlab = "filter length", ylab = "mean squared error", main = paste0(type, "\n derivative estimate"))

}


Example 2
Here's another example that illustrates the complications. Here $g(x)$ is a sum of a quadratic function and a sine wave function. You can see that the behaviour of $g'(x)$ is a lot different from $g(x)$.

The derivative $g'(x)$ makes a lot of oscillations and using a large bandwidth would result in a large bias for the estimate of the slope.

On the other hand for the function value $g(x)$ the effect of the oscillations in the derivative are less important as they even out, and using a large bandwidth would not result in a large bias for the estimate of the function value.




Conclusion
These examples show that the ideal bandwidth for estimating $g(x)$ might not tell you much about the ideal bandwidth for estimating $g'(x)$. You need some more direct way to estimate the bias variance tradeoff as function of the bandwidth.

Thanks for the really useful simple example. But then is there any rule/guidelines to pick the optimal bandwidth of the derivative function directly? The closest I got is Ruppert et al 1995 from the response above, that I still need to implement in R to see if it works for the derivative.

@G.Ander you will need some information, either from observations or from background knowledge. Fitting a larger bandwidth will reduce variance, but it increases the bias. You need some way to estimate the bias. The information from the cross validation with the function value may not be enough if the derivative has more and faster fluctuations than the the function value....

... why are you actually using cross validation to determine the bandwidth? You may also use an educated guess about the function behaviour. If you know a typical range over which the derivative remains fairly constant, then use that range as the bandwidth.

Thanks for the 2nd example as well. I m not supposed to have any guess about the behavior of the function. I know some ranges of values for which my estimation makes sense and that s what I m using so far, but I m writing a paper and I m trying to anticipate requests asking for an optimal bandwidth for the derivative and basically I have no idea so far. But I ll guess I ll just say that the cross validation bw has no reason to make any sense and that’s why I m not using it.

Update: after further investigation, here is what I found.
First, the RSC criterium from Fan & Gijbels (1996) can apply to derivative (even though I find its performance very disappointing in my case).
There is also work in Härdle (1990) section 5.1.4. talking about how to do the cross-validation for the first derivative. The intuition is that he builds "derivative" counterpart from the data by ordering the X and pairing some X and Y. This way you can build a MSE, the "constructed" derivative draws from the data serve as counterpart to Y in the MSE for the standard function.
In terms of implementation, lpbwselect() from the package nprobust by Calonico, Cattaneo and Farrell (2019, Journal of Statistical Software) implements several bandwidth (and adaptive bandwidth) from Fan & Gijbels (1996) and Wand and Jones (1995).
I am going to go for one of these in my case!
